# how to get div selectionstart and selectionend for firefox and ghroom?

Tags: javascript, selection-api

when Im using this code inside text area its working perfect bu i need it for my div the selectionstart and selectionend functions gives undefined values why can any one help me with this here are my code

```
{var textarea = document.getElementById("content_text");

if ($.browser.webkit || $.browser.mozilla) {
        var start = textarea.selectionStart;
        var end = textarea.selectionEnd;
        sel = textarea.value.substring(start, end); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the onclik event it will not work because its not getting the text but if you use the onmousdown event it will work